# mouseleave event fires late in vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a simple sidebar designed in `HTML` and I have developed a script where the sidebar closes and opens when the mouse enters and mouse leaves respectively.

You can check out the [DEMO](https://codepen.io/usamarehan/pen/VEQgBM) here.

I have used `Vue.js` instance for the whole sidebar, everything works perfectly except when the mouse hovers any of the items in the side bar then when the mouse leaves, the closing of the side bar is very slow.

Comment: There's a lot of jQuery embedded in there. You probably want to make a wrapper component or possibly a directive to properly segregate jQuery DOM manipulation from Vue DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) instead of `mouseover` ..

```
<div id="custom-erp-id-side-nav" class="custom-erp-side-nav" @mouseenter="openSideBar" @mouseleave="closeSideBar">
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzXYwB)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the animate time, for example set 50

```
closeSideBar: function() {
  $("#custom-erp-id-side-nav")
    .off()
    .animate({ left: "-230px" }, 50);
}
```

Comment: But that still does not answer for the delay when the animation time is > 200

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your problem. I have only see you said in the question 'when the mouse leaves, the closing of the side bar is very slow.' My suggestion can only solve this problem.

Comment: I don't want to change the animation time, it should be 300. How can I keep the time and make the event trigger faster?

Comment: hm, no idea. if you want the side bar to be closed immediately, why you want to keep the delay animation. sorry, can not help.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you're queueing up a lot of events. In some situations, you can get an opening-and-closing loop that keeps going until you move your mouse. This happens even if you use mouseenter instead of mouseover.

You can have your open and close routines each set a gatekeeper variable to ensure that they don't try multiple opens (or closes). In the `complete` parameter of `animate`, you unset the gatekeeper variable.

```
    openSideBar: function() {
      if (!this.opening) {
        this.opening = true;
        $("#custom-erp-id-side-nav")
          .off()
          .animate({
            left: "0px"
          }, null, null, () => {
            this.opening = false;
          });
      }
    },
    closeSideBar: function() {
      if (!this.closing) {
        this.closing = true;
        $("#custom-erp-id-side-nav")
          .off()
          .animate({
            left: "-230px"
          }, null, null, () => {
            this.closing = false;
          });
      }
    }
```

```js
// vue instance for the sidebar menu
var erp_custom_side_bar = new Vue({
  el: "#custom-erp-id-side-nav",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    //function to close/open the child elements
    //when the parent menu is clicked.
    toggleOpenChild: function(event) {
      var currentParent = $(event.currentTarget)
        .find(".custom-erp-menu-parent")
        .text();
      var childListID = currentParent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-");
      $(".custom-erp-menu-list > ul")
        .not($("#" + childListID + "-child"))
        .slideUp()
        .removeClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
      if ($("#" + childListID + "-child").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#" + childListID + "-child")
          .slideDown(300)
          .toggleClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
      } else {
        $("#" + childListID + "-child")
          .slideUp(300)
          .toggleClass("custom-erp-menu-child-open");
      }
    },
    openSideBar: function() {
      if (!this.opening) {
        this.opening = true;
        $("#custom-erp-id-side-nav")
          .off()
          .animate({
            left: "0px"
          }, null, null, () => {
            this.opening = false;
          });
      }
    },
    closeSideBar: function() {
      if (!this.closing) {
        this.closing = true;
        $("#custom-erp-id-side-nav")
          .off()
          .animate({
            left: "-230px"
          }, null, null, () => {
            this.closing = false;
          });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-erp-side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 56px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #2b333e;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: -230px;
}

.custom-erp-side-nav-open {
  left: 0;
}

.custom-erp-menu-list a {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #aeb7c2;
  display: block;
}

.custom-erp-menu-list>a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.custom-erp-menu-list a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: rgb(56, 65, 74);
}

.custom-erp-menu-list a:hover .custom-erp-module-list-icon {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.custom-erp-module-list-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #252c35;
  border-left: 3px solid #3cabfe;
}

.custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown>a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(56, 65, 74);
}

#custom-erp-menu-lists {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.custom-erp-menu-child-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-erp-id-side-nav" class="custom-erp-side-nav" @mouseover="openSideBar" @mouseleave="closeSideBar">

  <nav id="custom-erp-menu-nav">
    <ul id="custom-erp-menu-lists">
      <li class="custom-erp-menu-list" v-on:click="toggleOpenChild">
        <a href="#">
          <span>
       <img src="assets/images/dollar-bills.svg" class="custom-erp-module-list-icon custom-erp-user-icons" width="18" height="18" alt="">
      </span>
          <span class="custom-erp-menu-parent">Purchase Order</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown" id="purchase-order-child">
          <li><a href="page-profile.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="page-login.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="page-lockscreen.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Lockscreen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="custom-erp-menu-list" v-on:click="toggleOpenChild">
        <a href="#">
          <span>
       <img src="assets/images/dollar-bills.svg" class="custom-erp-module-list-icon custom-erp-user-icons" width="18" height="18" alt="">
      </span>
          <span class="custom-erp-menu-parent">Expense</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav custom-erp-menu-child-dropdown" id="expense-child">
          <li><a href="page-profile.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="page-login.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="page-lockscreen.html" class="custom-erp-menu-child">Lockscreen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a valid point and probably is the root cause of the problem. mouseover was just making it worse.

Comment: But when I use `mouseenter` the event is getting called only once when I am inside the side-menu div, there are not queuing up of events there. 

And what you are basically saying is that to use a variable when keeps track of whether it is open/closed?

Comment: If you shake the mouse so that it rapidly goes in and out of the region while the animation is running, you will get it to queue up a bunch of events. The variables keep track of whether it is in the middle of an animation.